# Variable in string PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, postgis, psql

I have code written in postgreSQL database:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist
FROM (SELECT
   'SRID=4326;POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)'::geography as gg1,
   'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)'::geography as gg2
   ) As foo  ;
```

and instead of 'POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)' and LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)' I want to add a point which is selected from table:

```
SELECT ST_asText(geog) FROM punkty WHERE gid = 1
```

How to add a selected variable into string in psql database?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

I might be oversimplifying your question, but simply adding both tables in the where clause or a join (if possible) would do it.

Example:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(t1.geog, t2.geog) As spheroid_dist, 
  ST_Distance(t1,geog, t2.geog, false) As sphere_dist
FROM 
  punkty2 t1, punkty2 t2 
WHERE t1.gid = 1 AND t2.gid = 2
```